# Backbone js Missing method 'template'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm practicing the use of external templates in Backbone js and I got this TypeError where it says that the object has no `template`.

Also how does the router recognizes/calls view if it is in another path and vice versa?

I've included the codes that I'm working on:

profile.js

```
window.ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
}
});
```

main.js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'profile' : 'profile'
    },
    profile: function() {
        this.profileView = new ProfileView();
        $('#global-content').html(this.profileView.el);
    }
});


utils.loadTpl (['profile'], function() {
    appRouter = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

utils.js

```
window.utils = {
loadTpl: function(views, callback) {

    var deferreds = [];

    $.each(views, function(index, view) {
        if (window[view]) {
            deferreds.push($.get('templates/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
            }));
        } else {
            // alert(view + " not found");
        }
    });

    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Template isn't a function, you need to call it as a property of the view so you should remove the `()`

e.g.

```
$(this.el).html(this.template);
```

Comment: right, it got rid of the error but the template still doesn't show up

Comment: How are you setting the template, it's not obvious in your code that you are.  Typically I use require.js to retrieve the resource, then I specifically set the template e.g. `template: template,` in the view itself

Comment: it was specified in utils.js. I intentionally didn't use require.js
in reference to [this](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/tree/master/public)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that method, I always use require.js.